# Different cloudpickle everytime the program is run

Tags: python, pickle, cloudpickle

Consider the following python code:

```py
import cloudpickle


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num


def outer(num):
    return Foo(num)


print(cloudpickle.dumps(outer))
```

This produces a different pickle everytime you run the code. Analysing the pickle file using `pickletools` shows the following diff:

```
144c144
<   552: \x8c         SHORT_BINUNICODE '2e3db4572bb349268962a75a8a6f034c'
---
>   552: \x8c         SHORT_BINUNICODE '89ee770de9b745c4bbe83c353f1debba'
```

Now, I understand that cloudpickle doesn't guarantee determinism of the pickle files. ([link](https://github.com/cloudpipe/cloudpickle/issues/453)), but I am curious why these two pickle files are different. It looks like the difference above is because of some sort of different hash for the `Foo` class.

Note that I ran the python program with a fixed `PYTHONHASHSEED`.

PS:
This is enough to reproduce the issue:

```py
import pickletools
import cloudpickle


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num


pickletools.dis(cloudpickle.dumps(Foo))
```

So it seems that each class has a property which gets baked into the cloudpickle, but I don't know what that property is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curious!

I dug into the source code and found that it's not a property of the class nor even a computed hash, it's [just a random identifier generated with `uuid4()` per class](https://github.com/cloudpipe/cloudpickle/blob/7ddb089ecbaac67f62aa4cf2bf1bccd9fbe684fc/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py#L105-L112).

That function gets called by [`_class_getnewargs()` here](https://github.com/cloudpipe/cloudpickle/blob/7ddb089ecbaac67f62aa4cf2bf1bccd9fbe684fc/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py#L112), which is called by [`_dynamic_class_reduce()` here](https://github.com/cloudpipe/cloudpickle/blob/7ddb089ecbaac67f62aa4cf2bf1bccd9fbe684fc/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py#L387), which has the comment

> Save a class that can't be stored as module global.
> This method is used to serialize classes that are defined inside functions, or that otherwise can't be serialized as attribute lookups
> from global modules.

Things are immediately much less complicated if the class is not in the `__main__` module (since `__main__` could be anything from the eventual unpickler's perspective); if you do `from b import outer` and cloudpickle *that* `outer`, you get

```
    0: \x80 PROTO      5
    2: \x95 FRAME      15
   11: \x8c SHORT_BINUNICODE 'b'
   14: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 0)
   15: \x8c SHORT_BINUNICODE 'outer'
   22: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 1)
   23: \x93 STACK_GLOBAL
   24: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 2)
   25: .    STOP
```

as the pickle instead of all the voodoo cloudpickle does to pickle something that is in `__main__`.

Comment: > if you do from b import outer and cloudpickle that outer

That is exactly how I solved the issue. For larger context, Kubeflow caching relies on determinism of cloud pickling.

Comment: Yet another good reason to properly (Python-)package your ML code from the get-go :)